# Make file executable by only typing name

Tags: python, bash, terminal

Might be a dumb question but when you install a package from homebrew you can run it simply by typing it's name. I was wondering how you can do that and what sort of script you would do it with? Does homebrew automatically make an alias for it or what? I want to know as I am making a tap atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute the scripts by name, you have to add your script path to the environment. One method is adding the `PATH` to the `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

```
export PATH=~/PathOfTheScript:$PATH
```

`echo $PATH` will list all the present directories already in the `PATH`. Typically applications are installed inside `/usr/bin` or `/bin` or etc and they are already inside the `PATH` by default.

Answer (score 1):

To execute programs by name, the path they are located in must be in the PATH environment variable. You can either place the file in a directory already in PATH, or add to it: https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/.
You edit `/etc/paths` and add a new line with your programs directory.